# consulta sql en mysql muestra registros repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta en la cual quiero obtener el nombre de un curso cuando un campo sea distinto el problema es que me muestra registros repetidos saben cual podria ser el problema. la consulta solo deberia mostrar cursos que no tiene asignado

tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

=============consulta sql=======================================

```
 SELECT CG.NOMBRE_CURSO 
 FROM curso_generico_relator cgr,curso_generico cg,relatores r
 where not cgr.RUT_RELATOR='23.709.392-5' 
 and cgr.ID_CURSO=cg.ID_CURSO
 and cgr.RUT_RELATOR=r.RUT_RELATOR
```

==========================resultado=======================================

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con una sola tabla contra curso_generico_relator (de las dos que pusiste); debe existir solo un registro caso contrario te falta considerar más en el "where".

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas `SELECT DISTINCT ... `? O sea, agregas `DISTINCT ` después del SELECT y veamos lo que ocurre.

Comment: Francamente, no creo que has descrito claramente la lógica de tu consulta. En particular, como se relaciona la expresión `where not cgr.RUT_RELATOR='23.709.392-5'` con tus requisitos *obtener el nombre de un curso cuando un campo sea distinto* y *mostrar cursos que no tiene asignado*. No está claro. Y aunque probablemente puedes "arreglar" el problema usando `DISTINCT`, creo que la forma correcta no es esa, mas bien se requiere entender bien la lógica de tu consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la consulta que indicas lo que estás pidiendo son todas las combinaciones que existen en `curso_generico_relator` que no correspondan al `rut_relator = '23.709.392-5'`.  Por el resultado que obtienes es claro que hay cursos que están relacionados con más de un relator.

Si lo que quieres es obtener la lista de cursos que no tiene asignado un relator entonces la puedes obtener con tu consulta agregando el operador `DISTINCT` o con una consulta que utilice el operador `NOT IN`:

```
select
    nombre_curso
from
    curso_generico
where
    id_curso not in (
        select
            id_curso
        from
            curso_generico_relator
        where
            rut_relator = '23.709.392-5'
    )
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta tienes razon como habia mas de un curso en la tabla se repetian.